# How to display value of LinePlot JPGraph when the mouse is over the graph line or tick point

Tags: jpgraph, line-plot

I have project to make a graph with many x axis value and it can't Display by show() function in display value class because it will overlap each other. So I want to display graph value only when the mouse is over the line or tick point. Is it possible to do that? If It possible how to do this.(and if it has other way that isn't JPGraph please advise me.)
thank you. :)
I don't know are you understand me. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because JPGraph is rendering a flat image, to the webpage this is the same as adding any flat image so it is unable to know what data piece your mouse is hovering over.

Answer (score 1):

give this example a try.
it is possible,even to add a link to another page.

```
  require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php'); // change to your libraries
  require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php'); // change to your libraries

 // Some random data to plot
 $datay=array(12,26,9,17,31);

 // Create the graph. 
 $graph = new Graph(400,250);
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

// Create a bar pot
$bplot = new BarPlot($datay);

// Create targets for the image maps so that the details are opened in a separate window
$fmtStr = "javascript:window.open('barcsim_details.php?id=%d','_new','width=500,height=300');void(0)";
$n = count($datay);
$targ=array();
$alts=array();
for($i=0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
    $targ[$i] = sprintf($fmtStr,$i+1);
    $alts[$i] = '%d'; 
    // Note: The format placeholder val=%d will be replaced by the actual value in the ouput HTML by the 
    // library so that when the user hoovers the mouse over the bar the actual numerical value of the bar 
    // will be dísplayed
}
$bplot->SetCSIMTargets($targ,$alts);

// Add plot to graph
$graph->Add($bplot);

// Setup the title, also wih a CSIM area
$graph->title->Set("CSIM with popup windows");
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT2,FS_BOLD);
// Assume we can give more details on the graph
$graph->title->SetCSIMTarget(sprintf($fmtStr,-1),'Title for Bar'); 

// Send back the HTML page which will call this script again to retrieve the image.
$graph->StrokeCSIM();
```

http://fossies.org/dox/jpgraph-3.0.7/barcsim__popup_8php_source.html

Answer (score 0):

$lineplot->value->Show();

check out value-method and some options

Answer (score -2):

The following function may be use your project. 
for example

```
clearviewport();
```

that is used in trubo c

Comment: Maybe Turbo C isn't very relevant when the question is about JPGraph, a component written in PHP.